# User Session Variable Not Being Set In Function

Tags: php, web-services, soap, session-variables

I am trying to pass user session variables within this function to get shipping quotes through ups.  The variables are not being set and I have tried to lookup different ways to set them without any luck.  This is just a snippet of the code and yes session start is at the beginning of the overall code.  Thanks for the help!

```
function processFreightRate()


{
      //create soap request
      $option['RequestOption'] = 'RateChecking Option';
      $request['Request'] = $option;
      $shipfrom['Name'] = 'Good Incorporation';
      $addressFrom['AddressLine'] = '2010 WARSAW ROAD';
      $addressFrom['City'] = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_cityID'];
      $addressFrom['StateProvinceCode'] = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_stateID'];
      $addressFrom['PostalCode'] = $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_zipID'];
      $addressFrom['CountryCode'] = 'US';
      $shipfrom['Address'] = $addressFrom;
      $request['ShipFrom'] = $shipfrom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$counter` is not defined, so it is unable to pull the value from session.  Pass the `$counter` variable into the function
  `function processFreightRate($counter)` and that may solve your issue.

Comment: added the $counter to the beginning of the function and that still didn't set the user value.

Comment: When you `print_r($_SESSION)`, what do you see?  Also, are you incrementing `$counter` somewhere outside the function?  What is the value of `$counter` when you are trying to use `$_SESSION['order'][$counter][....`?

Comment: I am not incrementing $counter somewhere else and I cant just print_r($_SESSION) because this is just one of about 25 shipping objects on the same file.

Comment: Without more information, this is very difficult to help you troubleshoot.  If you try to `echo $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['f_stateID'];`, do you see a value?  If you do, what does `print_r($addressFrom);` show?  If you don't, perhaps something is wrong with the value of `$counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$counter` is accessible by the function, also try doing a `var_dump()` of the `$_SESSION` variable to see what's being passed.

Comment: the values are being passed in the session because i can see them on the other soap objects that is on the same file.